# Migration AngularJS to Angular: How to migrate service which gets a controller reference

Tags: angular, angularjs

I am in the process of migrating an AngularJS-Application to Angular, component by component with the help of ngHybrid. So far it works, but now I stumbled upon an weird AngularJS-Service with a function which gets passed an AngularJS-Component-Controller as function parameter:

```
// Service
getDocumentList(requestData, ctrl) {
    // edits stuff on ctrl, like adding variables and modifying values
}

// calling component
var ctrl = this;
documentService.getDocumentList(requestData, ctrl);
```

I know I know, I for myself never would have created a service method which modifies a controller via passed reference, its horrible practice, but I am just migrating it and before refactoring it I'd rather make it work with as little effort as possible. I'm just not sure if it is possible with Angular to pass a reference, cause I don't have controllers anymore but classes... Is there a way to make it work it can I **only** refactor it so that the service returns something which the calling component works with (as it should be...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Angular component class usually fulfills controller functions. so the same code - passing `this` should work. but there can be issues with change detection, especially if you are using onPush strategy